# Python number can be only between y to x

Tags: python, numbers

can someone help me to solve this?

```
        if (bnb_spent) >= 0.00001 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.00004:
            # LOG.info(f'Nasrat, čislo je menší')
            pass
        else:    
            if (bnb_spent) >= 0.0003 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.0005:
                send_message1(message)
            else:
                if (bnb_spent) >= 0.08 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.1:
                    send_message2(message)
                else:
                    if (bnb_spent) >= 0.11 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.4:
                        send_message3(message)
```

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I expect it to send a message if the number is not less than 0.001 but at the same time is not greater than 0.003

Comment: Call `float(bnb_spent))` and save result in some variable before comparison. Also check what is `elif`.

Comment: what exactly is in `bnb_spent`, I'm assuming a string but a string of what?

Comment: bnb_spent = trade['amount1']
    bnb_spent = str(round(float(bnb_spent),3))

Comment: remove `str()` part? `bnb_spent = round(float(bnb_spent),3)`. what is `trade`?

Comment: you should add relevant details in OP. a [mcve] would be most helpful

Comment: *bnb_spent* is of type str. The TypeError makes that clear. You cannot make direct numerical comparisons between a string and a float. As others have said, you should try converting *bnb_spent* to float - i.e., *float(bib_spent)*. However, take care in case the string does not contain data that are convertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bnb_spent` parameter is a string when that part of code is executed. Try casting it to a float before comparing. You could try for example (also cleaned the if-else a bit):

```
        bnb_spent = float(bnb_spent)
        if (bnb_spent) >= 0.00001 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.00004:
            # LOG.info(f'Nasrat, čislo je menší')
            pass
        elif (bnb_spent) >= 0.0003 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.0005:
            send_message1(message)
        elif (bnb_spent) >= 0.08 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.1:
            send_message2(message)
        elif (bnb_spent) >= 0.11 and (bnb_spent) <= 0.4:
            send_message3(message)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but send_message1(message) is not processed.

Comment: If send_message1 is not being invoked, it's because bnb_spent is not in the inclusive range 0.0003 - 0.0005. Try printing bnb_spent after converting it. The value may not be what you expected

Answer (score 0):

Probably the variable `bnb_spent` is a string. Add the line `bnb_spent = float(bnb_spent)` before the given code segment.